# Javascript/jQuery get iFrame index

Tags: javascript, iframe, indexing

How can I get a specific iFrame index?

Say for example I have this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id='iframe'></iframe>
    <iframe id='randomiframe'></iframe>
    <iframe id='anotheriframe'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to get the index of #iframe (0) using javascript or jQuery.

Thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script> 

    /**
     * Get iframe index by Id 
     * @param iframe_id 
     * @return (int) | null - index of the iframe or null
     */

    function getIframeIndex(iframe_id)
    {

        var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for(i=0; i<iframes.length;i++){ 
            if(iframes[i].id == iframe_id){
                return i ;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    // call function pass id - 
    var iframe_index = getIframeIndex('iframe');

</script>
```